# Finding object in generic ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have `usersArrayList`, `messagesArrayList` and `chatsArrayList`, that are `ArrayList<User>`, `ArrayList<Message>` and`ArrayList<Chat>` respectively. Each of these classes has an `id` attribute.

I tried to write a generic function to find instance of given object in given list by `id` like that:

```
public static <T> T findInListById(ArrayList<T> list, String objId) {
        return list.stream().filter(listObj -> listObj.id.equals(objId)).findFirst();
}
```

But Java says that `listObj` doesn't have an `id` attribute. How do I write function so it works for `User`, `Chat` and `Message` classes?

**P.S.** I also tried writing a parent class `IDClass` for all of them, which solved the problem, but then when I tried to invoke it (`ID.findInListById(usersArrayList,userId)`), Java would complain:

```
Required Type: ArrayList<ID>
Provided: ArrayList<User>
```

Comment: probably you must declare `<T>` as `<T extends IDClass>`, that is, `public static <T extends IDClass> T findInListById(...` - no idea what class `ID` from the error is...

Comment: Unify the types using a type that exposes the ID. For example, your `IDClass` class. Then change the type parameter bounds to `<T extends IDClass>`. You might also want to change the `list` parameter to be a `Collection<? extends T>` (the `Collection` interface because it's typically best to be as abstract as possible, and the `? extends T` because the semantics of the method mean `list` is being used as a producer).